# Static Entity Framework db context in OData Controller

Tags: c#, entity-framework, rest, asp.net-web-api, odata

In OData tutorials for ASP.NET Web API, they always set the new `DbContext` as private property of controller.

```
public class LocationPropertiesController : ODataController
{
    Entities ctx = new Entities();

    [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<LocationProperties> Get()
    {
        return ctx.LocationProperties;
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        ctx.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

thinking that the dispose method will do the job.

But the reality is that the context, connection or anything else can fail and then I'm left with a disposed ctx that I cannot reuse at following request because the controller given to me is still the same instance.

On the other hand if the IQueryable is returned thet OData could perform filtering on the living thing, if I wrap that query in using(ctx...) then I become a thick client for the database.

So are we dealing with a design flaw in OData or what am I missing here?

Comment: *controller given to me is still the same instance* Are you sure?

Comment: your not making much sense. In your code... the context is made per  an instance of LocationPropertiesController which in itself will have an instance of (ctx ie context) when LocationPropertiesController  is disposed so will the ctx which is part of that instance.

Comment: A new Controller instance is always created for each new incoming request. That is the basis for MVC, Web API, and also the Odata controllers that are built on (and extend) the Web API controllers.

Comment: First, understand the oData expression tree is merged with your IQueryable before it is materialized on the database server. Second, you should look at using an IoC container to handle your context. Check out these links: https://damienbod.com/2014/06/19/web-api-odata-v4-using-unity-ioc-sqlite-with-ef6-and-odata-model-aliasing-part-5/   and   https://chsakell.com/2015/04/04/asp-net-web-api-feat-odata/

Comment: @Igor No it's not created for every request. After an error in request I then  keep getting entity context disposed exception on following requests.

Comment: @SteveGreene I understand that with ioc lifestyles i can user/create a per request lifestyle but I'm in a project now when a lot is done without it. I'm not sure if that revolution is required. We should be able to allow odata without ioc, yet currently when there is an error in one action, following calls to other actions will fail with "ef context disposed"...

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As of now what you have posted and your assumption of the cause of exception conflict. Once you have a MCV example it will be easier to help you pinpoint the root cause.